# How to return custom class from PagingAndSortingRepository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a model that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sale {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
  private User customer;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
  private Product product;
}
```

And I have a paging-and-sorting repository, like so:

```
public interface SaleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Sale, Long> {}
```

But I would like to the "findAll" method of the repository in order to return a custom class with certain fields (instead of all the data of the nested entities), while still maintain paging and sorting abilities.  The list of objects I would like to return would contain something like:

- saleId
- customerId
- customerName
- productId
- ProductName
- prouctPrice

***But I'm not sure how to actually do this.***

My controller method accepts sorting and paging parameters and then does this:

```
Page<Sale> saleList = saleRepository.findAll(pageable);

return saleList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create either and Interface or a DTO and use this as the result of a find declared in your repository:

```
Page<YourDTO> findAllAsDtos(Pageable pageable);
```

Read more about projections here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Thanks Simon. I hadn't seen that approach before, it seems like the easiest and most straightforward way to do it. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you should read the whole reference documentation of Spring Data JPA There are more hidden gems.